# How to install Syntek Driver Ubuntu 14.10 (WiFi)

Tags: wireless, drivers, internet

since i installed **Ubuntu 14.10 the WiFi don't work.**

Then, on terminal:
**lsusb --> "Syntek Semiconductor Co., Ltd 802.11g + Bluetooth Wireless Adapter"**

Ok, that's my Wireless thing, i searched how to install it driver, the only thing that i've found was:

> "$ git clone https://github.com/fsouza/3dsp.git $ cd 3dsp
>
> $ sudo bash Install_3DSPUSB.sh "

So, that worked, but.. Then, i can find an Application called 3DSP uWB, but that doesn't do nothing.

I also cannot find a **"3DSP WiFi Radar"** or something like that =(

Help pls, sorry for my bad english. Thanks in advance

Comment: Check whether the driver modules are properly loaded: `lsmod | grep 3dsp`

Comment: lsmod | grep 3dsp --> Don't return nothing, is that good? >.<

Comment: No, not good. Have you rebooted?

Comment: Yes, and rebooted again to make sure, but nothing =/

Comment: Wait, how is this driver related to Syntek?

Comment: Thats what i found: That i should install this driver to make the syntek thing work.. I don't know exactly. The syntek website only gives broken links to wireless drivers

Comment: Yes, I've seen that. But where did you read that these are Syntek drivers?

Comment: Here, it's in portuguese but: https://fredim.wordpress.com/2012/07/13/syntek-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: It's super hard to find something on google about it. LoL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've installed the wrong driver! These modules do not get associated with your wireless card and are therefore not loaded. Where did you get from that this is the correct driver?

I guess that there aren't drivers which work with 14.10 and the underlying kernel (yet)... I can't find anything about it on Google.